# LSTM preprocessing: Build 3d arrays from pandas data frame based on ID

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, keras, lstm

I am new to machine learning in keras and I am planning to conduct a machine learning experiment that predicts a sequence of the first ten items bought in a video game match based on a recurrent neural network with lstm layer(s).

Suppose an examplary table pre-sorted by `gameId`,`side`and `timestamp` is given:

```
       gameId   side   timestamp  itemId 
   3030038208    100        4260    1055 
   3030038208    100        4648    2010 
   3030038208    100        5036    3340 
   3030038208    100      291561    1001 
   3030038208    100      295807    1083 
   3030038208    100      296457    2010 
   3030038208    200        3257    1055 
   3030038208    200        3516    2003 
   3030038208    200        3775    3340 
   3030038208    200      321461    1038 
   3030038208    200      321818    2003 
   3030038208    200      321979    2003 
   3030038208    200      491099    3006 
   3030038208    200      492238    1042 
   3030038208    200      743864    3086 
   3030038208    200      744773    1043
         ....
```

I now would like to reshape the dataframe into a two (x and y) 3d numpy array in which the third dimension describes the length of the purchase-sequence (`ItemId`) - such that essentially every 2d numpy array in the resulting sequence constitutes a table for the same `gameId`, `side` pair

Before training the Neural Network I would also need to insert a padding since the time series as mentioned above would be 10. In this example a padding value of 0 would seem alright, however in the real scenario I am working with a sparse matrix that includes a lot of 0 values.

Now here are some questions:

1) are there any built-in functions for either numpy, pandas or even keras to efficiently achieve my stated goals. I can't think of something that wouldn't take me ages to come up with a sensible preprocessing function.

2) are there any other considerations that need to be taken care of? especially in the case of padding. Would filling in "-999" not make more sense when dealing with sparse matrices?

3) Suppose the model would look something like that

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2, input_dim=1))
model.add(Dense(y.shape[1], activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['acc'])
monitor = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=1e-3, patience=5, verbose=0, mode='auto')
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=filepath + "best_weights.hdf5", verbose=0, save_best_only=True)
```

With:

```
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=2, validation_split=0.33, callbacks=[monitor, checkpointer], verbose=0).history
```

How would I be able to employ a masking layer correctly that takes care of the padding?

Thanks in advance for any second spent on that thread!

**edit**: 
on request, here are the resulting numpy arrays (I think) I would like to get in order to predict the `itemId` based on the `timestamp` with a neural network with lstm layers in keras **before padding**:

```
y = [
[1055, 2010, 3340, 1001, 1083, 2010],
[1055, 2003, 3340, 1038, 2003, 2003, 3006, 1042, 3086, 1043],
...
]

x = [
[[4260], [4648], [5036], [291561], [295807], [296457]],
[[3257], [3516], [3775], [321461], [321818], [321979], [491099], [492238], [743864], [744773] ],
...
]
```

and **after** padding:

```
y = [
[1055, 2010, 3340, 1001, 1083, 2010, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1055, 2003, 3340, 1038, 2003, 2003, 3006, 1042, 3086, 1043],
...
]

x = [
[[4260], [4648], [5036], [291561], [295807], [296457], [0], [0], [0], [0]],
[[3257], [3516], [3775], [321461], [321818], [321979], [491099], [492238], [743864], [744773] ],
...
]
```

However, there will be more features than just timestamp in the real example.

Comment: Can you add what the expected numpy array for x and y would look like, also why would y be 3d given the current structure of your lstm

Comment: You are right, y would be 2 dimensional in this case considering time steps. Corrrected it.

Comment: what are your x and y?

Comment: timestamp und itemId. I have set up an example in the edited version of the original post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this with a few steps by extracting data from a pandas groupby object. In the first two steps we will create the groupby object so that we can operate on it later on in the code. From the groupby object, we will find the largest group, so that that we can pad with zeros accordingly

```
gb = df.groupby(['gameId','side']) # Create Groupby object
mx = gb['side'].size().max() # Find the largest group
```

The steps for creating x & y are very similar. We can use list comprehension to loop over each group, convert the dataframes into numpy arrays and pad with zeros using [`np.pad()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html). Then reshape each array to be 3d

```
x = np.array([np.pad(frame['timestamp'].values,
                     pad_width=(0,mx-len(frame)),
                     mode='constant',
                     constant_values=0) 
                     for _,frame in gb]).reshape(-1,mx,1)

y = np.array([np.pad(frame['itemId'].values,
                     pad_width=(0,mx-len(frame)),
                     mode='constant',
                     constant_values=0) 
                     for _,frame in gb]).reshape(-1,mx,1)
```

---

In this example, the setup is for a many-to-many lstm. In the comments I had pointed out that your current setup would not support a 3d output value, because in the lstm layer you did not have the argument `return_sequence=True`.

Its unclear which structure you are looking for in this problem. I like to consult the following image when deciding which LSTM network I am using. The code Above will support a many-to-many network, assuming you add `return_sequence=True` to your LSTM layer. If you wanted many-to-one instead, drop `.reshape(-1,mx,1)` from y, and now you have a network with `mx` outputs.

[image]

---

For either setup, you need to modify the `input_shape` argument for your model. This argument must specify the shape of your 2nd and 3rd dimensions of x i.e.

```
                                                        # v Use input_shape here
model.add(LSTM(128, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2, input_shape=x.shape[1:]))
```

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate explaination: In regards to the cardinality of the problem, my guess would be a many-to-many lstm layer, since I would like the predictor to give me the entire sequence based on a set of timestamps. 

However, I forgot to mention that previously in my other keras neural network, I used to one-hot-encode y. would it even be a problem in this case or is putting `pd.get_dummies(frame['itemId'])values` instead of `frame['itemid'].values` valid enough? 

also, how am i going to split the data up into train and test when these are 3d? does train_test_split do the job?

Comment: The issues with using get dummines is that if each group does not have all categories, the values will not align. You should use sklearns categorical encoder, fit that to the unique values itemId and zero since that is the pad value, then you can fit those values in the list comprehension.

Comment: @DJK If we apply pd.get_dummies before applying groupby operation, then I think their should be no problem, if all groups do not have all categories.

Comment: @DJK I have similar problem. If I have more feature, then what changes should I need in code to make array x? Do I need to create multiple array and concatenate them, or their is some other simple solution. What change should I do in input_shape parameter of LSTM layer?

Comment: How would you do it differently if your gameid was a string?

Comment: With this answer (which I appreciate), the padding would add to the width as well as the height...to add only to the height, I changed pad_width to:  pad_width=((0,mx-len(frame)),(0,0))

Comment: How to make above code work if instead of just *"timestamp"* there are multiple features?

Comment: @DJK Appreciate any help to make the above code work for multiple features.

Comment: @Sanguine, you should be able to use basic pandas [slicing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html) to create a data frame, not a series. Though I’ll admit, it’s been a while since I’ve touched on this subject in ML