# Converting pandas dataframe to 3D array as input to LSTM model

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, keras, lstm

**Pandas dataframe:**

| id | feature1 | feature2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2234 | 13 |
| 1 | 2235 | 12 |
| 2 | 3344 | 12 |
| 2 | 3364 | 14 |
| 2 | 3354 | 9 |

**Problem:**

There are more than 2 features in the data on which model needs to be trained.
Each id can have multiple rows, so need to group by id to get the sequence data for each id.
And then convert it to 3d numpy array as required by LSTM model

**Already tried**
Tried solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49803503/lstm-preprocessing-build-3d-arrays-from-pandas-data-frame-based-on-id), and it works for single feature though I need it for multiple features.

Appreciate any help here.

Comment: may [this](https://ai4water.readthedocs.io/en/latest/utils.html#ai4water.utils.utils.prepare_data) can help you!